# Как в listBox добавить все текстовые файлы из папки?

Tags: c#, winforms, файлы

При запуске программы (WindowsFromsApp) в listBox должны отображаться все элементы(то бишь текстовые файлы), которые находятся в определенной папке. Как это реализовать?

Comment: И что, совершенно никаких своих мыслей на этот счет?

Comment: Перечисление файлов из каталога, выбор нужных, помещение в список. В чем конкретно проблемы?

Comment: `listBox.DataSource = Directory.GetFiles(path);`

Comment: уточните текстовые это *.txt только? или *.csv тоже? ещё какие-нибудь расширения? а может нужно не взирая на расширение определить, что файл текстовый?

Comment: только .txt файлы

Answer (score 2):

Вот так можешь отфильтровать нужное расширение

```
string file;
string[] inf = Directory.GetFiles( filename, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories );
                foreach ( var info in inf )
                {

                    file = Path.GetExtension(info);

                    if(file == ".mp3")
                    {
                        listBox.Items.Add( info );
                    }
                }
```

Comment: еще нужно отфильтровать текстовые

Comment: Автор не уточнял что ему надо отфильтровывать, я показал от себя пример.

Comment: @Sergey_73, пример не безопасен из-за 'SearchOption.AllDirectories' . Если попадется папка на которую нет прав, то вылетит исключение и ничего не вернется.