# Как получить путь относительно базового каталога в C#?

Tags: c#

В проекте на **WinForms** имеется набор отчетов, расположенных в папке и её подпапках, например:

```
D:\Shared\Common\BaseReports\Main.rpt
D:\Shared\Common\BaseReports\Main_new.rpt
D:\Shared\Common\BaseReports\2015\Payments.rpt
D:\Shared\Common\BaseReports\2016\Payments.rpt
```

и т.д.
Само приложение может располагаться где угодно, а путь к отчетам в нём указывается через переменную `string reportPath = "D:\\Shared\\Common\\BaseReports";`

В дальнейшем пусть путь к конкретному отчету задается с использованием базовой папки, например, так: `string someReport = reportPath + "\\2015\\Payment.rpt";`

**Как получить список папок и файлов, находящихся внутри D:\Shared\Common\BaseReports\ в виде:**

```
Main.rpt
Main_new.rpt
2015\Payments.rpt
2016\Payments.rpt
```

**... ?**

Да, про `string.Replace()` [`string relativePath = someReport.Replace(reportPath, "");`] знаю, но может быть есть способ лучше?
Спасибо!

Comment: https://ideone.com/vrQuf3 - но я не уверен что этот код будет работать всегда

Comment: @PavelMayorov: https://ideone.com/cLe7wf

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Спасибо, на английской версии портала [рекомендация аналогичная](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9045399)

Comment: @BlackWitcher что - "спасибо"? Не работает же )

Comment: @PavelMayorov работает, если в вашем коде заменить `@"D:\Shared\Common\BaseReports";` на `@"D:\Shared\Common\BaseReports\";`, т.е. добавить обратный слэш в конце root-пути.

Comment: @BlackWitcher посмотрите код, который привел VladD

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, увидел "баг" — заменяет пробел на %20, а так же может заменить обратный слэш на обычный, (в случае вложенных папок, например), т.е. если сделать так: `string file = @"D:\Shared\Common\BaseReports\Another Folder\Another Main.rpt;`

Comment: [Вот тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/703292) еще вариант ответа, но это именно то, от чего хотелось бы уйти.
Ибо тогда уж лучше так: 
1

Comment: Так, это вот (не успел в предыдущем комментарии запостить изменения):

    `string file = @"D:\Shared\Common\BaseReports\Another Folder\Another Main.rpt";`
    `string root = @"D:\Shared\Common\BaseReports";`
    `MessageBox.Show(file.Substring(root.Length));`

Comment: @BlackWitcher а зря хотите уйти, кстати. Именно в вашем случае такой способ работает без ошибок.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, согласен, потому внес изменения в [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/574043/222168). Использовать Replace или Substring в данном контексте не принципиально.

Comment: @PavelMayorov В общем-то согласен с ответом. Отредактировал свой, в принципе стали чем-то похожи. Впредь прежде чем минусовать чужие ответы - точнее формулируйте вопросы, друзья.

Comment: @V.Dmitriy вопрос был сформулирован точно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как то так.

```
var baseDir = new DirectoryInfo("H:\\...\\Reports");
foreach(var file in baseDir.EnumerateFiles("*.rpt",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Console.WriteLine(file.FullName.Replace(baseDir.FullName + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, 
        string.Empty));
}
```

Работает с любой глубиной вложенных папок. Минимум должен быть доступ на чтение для файлов и папок, в противном случае будет исключение, но если это пользовательская папка и программа может писать туда отчеты с правами пользователя, то проблем с доступом быть не должно (диверсия пользователя не в счет). Выводит правильные системные слеши в путях. Работает быстрее чем с использованием `Directory.GetFiles()`

Comment: Спасибо, то, что нужно.

Comment: пользуйтесь, в качестве бонуса, FileInfo сам умеет открывать и возвращать поток файла.

Answer (score 6):

В качестве модификации [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/574113/222168) @rdorn небольшая вариация на тему:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetRelativeFolderContents (string folder, string searchPattern = "*")
    {
        //Проверки на валидность параметров
        if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
        {
            //Нет пути для сканирования содержимого директории
            throw new IOException("Путь \"" + folder + "\" не существует.");
        }

        //Проверяем наличие разделителя папок в конце базового пути, и, если его нет - добавляем.
        if (!folder.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString())) folder += Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;

        //Список для результата:
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        //Временная переменная:
        string t = "";

        //Получаем содержимое базового пути, включая все вложенные папки и файлы:
        foreach (var item in Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(folder, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            t = item.Replace(folder, string.Empty);
            //Проверяем, не ссылку ли на папку мы получили?
            if (Directory.Exists(item))
            {
                //Папка пустая?
                if (!Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(item).Any())
                {
                    //Если пустая - добавляем к результату (не пустые папки сами добавятся вместе с 
                    //путями к файлам, в них содержащимся)
                    if (!item.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()))
                    {
                        result.Add(t + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.Add(t);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(t);
            }
        }
        return result; 
    }
```

Основные отличия - незначительные, а именно - дополнительные проверки и использование `Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries`, и, как следствие, в результат выборки попадут пустые папки, если они есть и параметры поиска допускают это.

Будет работать в .NET 4.0 и выше.

Comment: Советую добавить принудительное приведение путей к абсолютному (на тот случай, если пользователь поставит в настройках неправильный разделитель).

Comment: Также из соображений защитного программирования надо поставить проверку `file.StartsWith(root)`, при провале - кидать исключение

Comment: Я ниже откорректировал ответ. Вполне даже работают.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, спасибо, согласен. Но "защиту от дурака" равно как и прочие обработки исключений сознательно оставил за скобками, дабы не загромождать лишний раз.

Comment: @BlackWitcher в своем проекте - пожалуйста, оставляйте за скобками. Потому что если возникнет ошибка - вы ее почините. А вот когда выкладываете код в общий доступ - будьте готовы, что им воспользуется кто-нибудь имеющий меньше знаний чем вы.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, логично. Замечание принимается.

Answer (score 0):

Если приложение планируется использовать без VS. То можно использовать "Получение пути к директории исполняемого файла"

```
new FileInfo(String.Concat(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)).Directory.FullName
```

и в нем уже произвести поиск файлов с расширением `.rpt`

А если приложение будет работать только с VS то можно использовать EnvDTE.

Поиск и фильтр файлов можно сделать как в ручную так и с помощью структуры `DirectoryInfo`. Если совсем до мануала не добраться, могу написать как.

Пишу как:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string root = @"D:\Trash";

        List<string> files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Trash", "*.cpp", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
        List<string> relPath = new List<string>();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            relPath.Add(file.Replace(root,""));
            Console.WriteLine(file.Replace(root, ""));
        }

    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: VS, а так же место размещения приложения совершенно не привязаны к сути вопроса.
А точнее, у пользователя на рабочей станции №1 приложение установлено в C:\MyApp, а отчеты в D:\Work\Reports\
У пользователя на рабочей станции №2 приложение стоит в D:\Program Files\My_Work_Application, а отчеты лежат в C:\Рабочие отчеты.

Просто в настройках программы на каждом рабочем месте пользователь сам указывает путь к отчетам, и на каждом инстансе он РАЗНЫЙ, но программа его знает (из конфигурации). и этот путь совершенно не обязательно привязан к EXE или AppData.

Comment: @BlackWitcher. Создай Profil.ini и храни все настройки там. То есть Юзер указал путь к рабочей папке, программно сохранил в Profil.ini. При запуске программы считывай его.

Comment: Да дело не в сохранении конфигурации ведь, она итак хранится в Application.config, и там как раз путь к отчетам указан.
Задача в другом - в том, как получить разницу между 2-мя абсолютными путями.

Comment: Еще один пример того как никто не читает вопрос...

Comment: @BlackWitcher там ниже, был ответ который ты поставил минус, читай внимательнее.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042861/how-to-make-an-absolute-path-relative-to-a-particular-folder/9045399#9045399

Comment: Я читал как раз, т.к. заинтересован в решении вопроса, который сам и задал. А по ссылке - там достаточно заменить
`C:\RootFolder\SubFolder\MoreSubFolder\LastFolder\SomeFile.txt` на
`C:\RootFolder\SubFolder\More Sub Folder\LastFolder\Папка\Some File.txt` и запустить код, что бы увидеть, что результат будет не корректным.

А как раз этот ответ помог: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20144184

Спасибо!

Comment: Отлично. Теперь вам надо убрать первую часть ответа и цикл, потому что они не имеют отношения к задаче - и останется мое решение с Uri, которое неправильное.

Comment: @PavelMayorov теперь правильное?

Comment: Нет. Там проблема не только в пробелах.

Answer (score -1):

Не проще тогда использовать стандартную папку `%appdata%` и хранить все свои данные в ней?

```
string Path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string someReport = Path + "\\Shared\\Common\\BaseReports\\";
```

А чтобы найти файлы, нужно пробежаться по всем папкам вот пример:

```
string file;
string[] inf = Directory.GetFiles( someReport, "*.rpt", SearchOption.AllDirectories );
foreach ( var info in inf )
{
        //Что-то делаешь
}
```

Comment: А теперь, внимание, вопрос: что в вашем способе будет содержаться в переменной `info` и как получить из этого относительный путь? :)

Comment: Все твои файлы .rpt

Comment: @Sergey_73. не проще, к сожалению. Базовая папка может меняться от рабочей станции к рабочей станции и задает ее юзер. То, что внутри базовой папки - неизменно (условно не изменно).

Comment: @Sergey_73 а конкретнее?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov. Почитай, взял от сюда. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/564308/Как-в-listbox-добавить-все-текстовые-файлы-из-папки/564376#564376

Comment: @Sergey_73 нет, это вы запустите и проверьте. То, что где-то такой способ оказался удачным, не означает что он решает другую проблему другого автора.

Comment: @ Pavel Mayorov. У меня работает отлично. Мне запускать не надо, из моей программы код я вырезал, уже год все работает нормально,

Comment: С поиском файлов по маске (или набору расширений) включая вложенные подпапки проблем нет, чего спорить-то? ))

Comment: Да я не спорю, просто человеку интересно.)

Comment: @BlackWitcher потому я и спорю, что у вас с этим проблемы нет. А значит, этот "ответ" на ваш вопрос не отвечает. Более того, он сводит вашу исходную проблему к самой себе.